# Is the same using cache() and using persist() function with no parameteres in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is there any major difference in any term between `persist()` no parameters and `cache()`?

I know that if you use `cache()`, the parameteres of the storage level are set by default and in `persist()` you can edit these parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, actually cache() is an alias for persist, looks how it looks in code:

[Source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L3630)

```
/**
   * Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def cache(): this.type = persist()
```

And persist without parameters which is called from within cache is:

```
/**
   * Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).
   *
   * @group basic
   * @since 1.6.0
   */
  def persist(): this.type = {
    sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery(this)
    this
  }
```